# Play framework : Request_denied when getting json from googlemap url

Tags: json, google-maps, url, frameworks, playframework

I am working on **play framework 2.1.1** (java) and **googlemap v3** (local website).

I want to get latitude and longitude using googlemap url.
I want this url return me **json** response to parse it later and insert lat and long in my database.
It works fine when it's not a googlemap url but i have the famous **"request_denied"** error when I use this kind of url in my code:

***http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Paris&sensor=false***

I don't know why, I read this error come from the lack of the sensor parameter but as you can see it's in my url.

About my code :

```
public static Result displaySomeJson(){
    Promise<WS.Response> request= WS.url("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Paris&sensor=false").get();
    JsonNode json = request.asJson();
    return ok(json.toString())
}
```

it gives me : **{"results" : [],"status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"}**

- I also tried with **http ://maps.GOOGLE.com** instead of  **http ://maps.GOOGLEAPIS.com** but i got the same result.
- I also tried using **an api key** but it failed again.
- I didn't send to much request.

If you have any suggestion, please share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok i found this way :

```
Promise<WS.Response> request =
WS.url("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json")
.setQueryParameter("address",adresse).setQueryParameter("sensor", "true")
.post("content");
```

Then i parsed it :

```
String lat = request.get().asJson().path("results").get(0).get("geometry").get("location").get("lat").toString();
String long = request.get().asJson().path("results").get(0).get("geometry").get("location").get("lng").toString();
```

I don't know if it's a "clear" way to do that, but it works fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Play 2. After changing the WS.url to the old fashioned way with a HttpUrlConnection it worked. Don't know why the WS.url is not working.

```
URL theUrl = new URL("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Paris&sensor=false");
HttpURLConnection urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) theUrl.openConnection();
...
```